# How to identify the correct Get/Post method in webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

```
I want to implement two get methods based on different id in web api service
eg:
// GET api/Data/5

 public List<Data> GetMyDatas(int id)
// GET api/Data/15
 public List<Data> GetMyDatas(int studid).
```

if i call this from my mvc controller how is it going to identify which get method it is getting called. is there a way to say this. I am having one mvc project and another mvc webapi1 project. i call the webmethod from my mvc project. VS 2010 , MVC 4 , Web API 1.

Comment: You'll need two different routes. You can't have matching routes with identical parameters unless you're using routing attributes: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Does it support web api 1

Comment: Yes this is possible in Web API 1 also but you will need to do so using a Nuget package.

Comment: i am not finding [RoutePrefix(")]

Comment: Download https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi then follow http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I am referring http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 . to implement in my web api 1 . Now i am getting RoutePrefix attribute. But [Route] Attribute is missing

Comment: which library needed for Route Attribute

Comment: Is [httpRoute] same as [Route] attribute?

Comment: Where are you seeing `[httpRoute]`? The correct attribute to use is `[Route]`

Comment: I am not finding [Route] attribute .please note i am using vs 2010 and web api 1. after insttalling attribute routing

Comment: Have you got the required namespaces? `using AttributeRouting;` and `using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;`

Comment: And are you following this guide? http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Yes, i did the route registration and importing of the namespace

Answer (score 2):

Your code is going to produce a compile time error because you have 2 methods with same name.

What you should do is, create a 2 seperate methods and use different url patterns for that.

With attribute routing enabled,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public List<string> GetMyDatas(int id)
    {
        return new List<string> {"product 1", "value2", id.ToString()};
    }

    [Route("Students/{studId}")]
    public List<string> GetStudentDatas(int studid)
    {
        return new List<string> { "student", "Students", studid.ToString() };
    }
}
```

The first method can be accessed like `yourSite/api/products/3` and second one can be accessed like `yourSite/api/products/Students/3` where 3 can be replaced with a valid number

Another option is to add a second parameter to your single action method and based on the parameter, determine what data to return.

```
public List<string> GetMyDatas(int id,string mode="")
{
    //based on the mode value, return different data.
    return new List<string> {"product 1", "value2", id.ToString()};
}
```

Comment: I feel web api1 doesnt support attribute routing .i am not able to add RoutePrefix("api/products")

Comment: Then add a second parameter to the single method as explained in the second part of the answer.

Comment: I dont want to add a second parameter actually.

Comment: Then either you need to update your route definitions to include the action method in the route pattern or create a second controller for Students.

Comment: Is it possible with different method name? can you show me a sample for pdate your route definitions to include the action method in the route pattern